# Using onblur to set custom validation using setCustomValidity()

Tags: javascript, validation

I'm trying to make custom validation using setCustomValidity(), it's work only when user submit the form. How can i set it on onblur , validate the textbox while user enter the value ? any help would be appreciated.

```
input type="text" name="YEAR" id="YEARMAKE" value="" required="true" oninput="validate(this)" />

function validate(input) 
{
    var yearlength = input.value;
if (yearlength.length < 4) {
    input.setCustomValidity('The year must have 4 digits');
    return false;
} else {
    input.setCustomValidity('');
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
input type="text" name="YEAR" id="YEARMAKE" value="" required="true" onblur="validate(this)" />

function validate(input) 
{
    var yearlength= document.getElementById(input);
if (yearlength.length < 4) {
    input.setCustomValidity('The year must have 4 digits');
    return false;
} else {
    input.setCustomValidity('');
    return true;
}
```

it will call function on lost focus..

Answer (score -2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>



Enter your Year: <input type="text" id="myInput" onblur="return validate(this)">

<script>
function validate(i)
{

var yearlength = i.value;

if (yearlength.length < 4) {
alert('The year must have 4 digits');
return false;
 } else {
    alert('');
    return true;
}

}
```

Rahter than writing your method I've just added the alerts